# What does the pokeball loading icon indicate?

Tags: pokemon-go

I noticed, that when I freshly connected into the game (or sometimes during playing) a pokeball appears which probably symbolizes loading (see screenshot).

But what does it indicate ...

- ... Server issues?
- ... Client connection issues?
- ... Location service issues?
- ... Other problems?

[image: loadingball]

In this example the server seems to be one problem as the bar in the right bottom, which displays near pokemon, is empty. Is this assumption correct?

Another hint for this is the empty shop page:

[image: emptystore]

I couldn't find a site where I can check the server status as well.

Comment: Here's a site that shows the status for the various regional servers.
http://www.mmoserverstatus.com/pokemon_go

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This icon means the game is communicating with Niantic's servers, ***for any reason.***

This includes, but is not limited to:

- Map/Inventory/Pokedex Updates
- Verifying/Recording a Pokemon's capture
- Verifying/Recording the use of an item, or a hack/battle
- Among other actions.

Comment: You should see this go off several times a minute while you're on the map screen, especially if you're moving (basically, it's polling to see if there are Pokemon near you). However, if it just spins endlessly and never goes away, there's a server or connection issue, and you may want to try restarting the game.

Comment: ^ This is basically the current behaviour for me and all of my friends in the Netherlands. At least these days while Niantic seems to struggle with their servers.

Answer (score 4):

The icon depicts that the map and surroundings are updated, just as in Ingress. I have this icon many times, mostly when moving, but I am still able to check-in or catch Pokémon.

Comment: The Pokéball is mostly rotating for me although I am in the same WLAN and don't move physically.

Comment: That's probably because the servers are steaming right now. It's just the app retrieving information, not indicating an error