# Why can't I get Pokéballs from the Pokéstops on my son's account, who is on holiday?

Tags: pokemon-go

My son is in Portugal on holiday, and can't find any Pokéstops. So, I logged in to his account here to walk to some local ones here and it won't give me any  Pokéballs. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 7):

Since cheating has been a huge issue in this game, I would certainly not recommend logging into one account from 2 separate countries simultaneously. The account may be soft banned, see here: [Why can't I catch Pokemon in Pokemon Go anymore?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/274315/why-cant-i-catch-pokemon-in-pokemon-go-anymore)